# Decrease indexing time ElasticSearch - RabbitMQ setup

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq

I am consuming millions of messages (each message has 10 fields) from RabbitMQ and pushing it to ElasticSearch. The ingestion as of now is taking 13-14 hours. What can I do to optimize the process ? Here are some approaches that I have tried till now :

- Creating multiple parallel connections to RabbitMQ server. I have 8
  connections to RabbitMQ server and am pre-fetching 500 messages in
  each channel.
- Using bulk indexing API for ElasticSearch. I am batching messages in
  each connection and bulk indexing 500 documents in a single go.
- Have created explicit mapping file for ElasticSearch, disabled _all
  field.

Still I don't see a good throughput (100 messages/sec) only. What other optimizations can I do to decrease the indexing duration and boost throughput to a much higher number ?

Thanks.

Comment: Without detailed information about your set up (number of nodes, cpu, memory, disk size, number of indexes, number of shards, desired ingestion volume, query volume, etc) it will be very difficult to help you.

Comment: Try playing with refresh intervals and related stuff